# Brackets Tag Colors

Tags: adobe-brackets

I just updated my version of Brackets to be most current. The colors that denote different tags has changed. The colors selected are too light, and I would like to change them, but I can't find where to do that. I tried to go to the View menu and select customized tag colors, but it is asking for a file. I did a search but everything that comes up with the name brackets is generally not brackets the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can make original css file and change tags color from View -> customize tag colors.